# Defining interface dependency that implements generics

Tags: c#, .net, generics

This will be generics 101 for many but below is sample code so I can understand better.

```
public interface IRecordedItemsProcessor<T>
{
    ObservableCollection<RecordedItem> Load(string name);
    void Save();
    RecordedItem Parse(T itemToParse);
}

public class FileLoadingProcessor : IRecordedItemsProcessor<string>
{
    public ObservableCollection<RecordedItem> Load(string name)
    {
    }

    public void Save()
    {
    }

    public RecordedItem Parse(string itemToParse)
    {
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(IRecordedItemsProcessor<T> processor)
    {

    }

}
```

The issue is that `MyClass` needs a dependency on `IRecordedItemsProcessor<T>` but will not compile as it does not know what `T` is. How can this be resolved? Making MyClass implement a  seems odd as all it needs to do is call Load/Save

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

**First solution** is the most simple one: lift generic declaration  to class level, like

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
    public MyClass(IRecordedItemsProcessor<T> processor)
    {

    }
}
```

Then you could instantiate `MyClass` as following:

```
var myClass = new MyClass<string>(new FileLoadingProcessor());
Console.WriteLine (myClass);
```

**Second solution** is a removing generic input from constructor and inferring types. Then you don't need to specify generic exactly from call. Class declaration will look like:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void Process<T>(IRecordedItemsProcessor<T> processor)
    {

    }
}
```

And then you can call simply

```
var my = new MyClass();
my.Process(new FileLoadingProcessor());
```

The Idea is that you always need to specify class-level generics explicitly, but method level generics can be inferred by the compiler.

**Third solutions** is to encapsulate creation mechanisms inside `MyClassFactory`. This is quite flexible, but it might seem a little bit complicated, because descendants of `IRecordedItemsProcessor<T>` don't define generic at class level, so we should go to implemented interfaces and grab there generic types. And only then we can construct Generic `MyClass`. Listing is given below:

```
public class MyClassFactory
{
    public MyClass<T> MakeMyClassFor<T>(IRecordedItemsProcessor<T> processor)
    {
        var processorGenericType = processor.GetType()
                                            .GetInterfaces()
                                            .Single(intr=>intr.Name == "IRecordedItemsProcessor`1")
                                            .GetGenericArguments()[0];
        var myClassType = typeof(MyClass<>).MakeGenericType(processorGenericType);
        return Activator.CreateInstance(myClassType, processor) as MyClass<T>;
    }
}
```

Now you can create MyClass very simply

```
 var myClassFactory = new MyClassFactory();
 var res = myClassFactory.MakeMyClassFor(new FileLoadingProcessor());
 Console.WriteLine (res);
```

All of these three approaches have their pros and cons. Consider taking into account the context, in which you are going to use them.

Comment: I don't want to do that. Why should MyClass have a <T> on it? I want MyClass to work with IRecordedItemsProcessor

Comment: Your comment suggests that your interface should be split into two interfaces, if some consumers of it don't care about some of its methods.

Comment: But you would want to use dependency injection for handling the IRecordedItemsProcessor so how would that work using a method. I've only ever seen DI work with constructors/properties.

Comment: To support DI you can inject Processor Provider or Processor Factory, that will create correct Processors, like FileLoadingProcessor

Comment: But the factory would have to implement T as well so it knows what type of T to return

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

1. Create a new interface `IRecordedItemsProcessor` (non-generic)
2. Move `Load` and `Save` to this `IRecordedItemsProcessor`
3. Make `IRecordedItemsProcessor<T>` inherit from this `IRecordedItemsProcessor`
4. Make `MyClass` expect `IRecordedItemsProcessor` in its constructor

This makes it clear that `MyClass` doesn't care what type the processor might be able to parse, or even that it can parse things at all - it only knows that it can save and load.

Comment: That would work and Parse could be kept public simply for unit testing. My class doesnt have to call Parse

Answer (score 0):

The generic type, as written, is being declared on the `MyClass` constructor which means the generic type must be defined at the `MyClass` level:

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
    public MyClass(IRecordedItemsProcessor<T> processor)
    {

    }
}
```

However, if the generic type was declared at a method level, it would only have to be defined at the method level:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void MyMethod<T>( IRecordedItemsProcessor<T> processor )
    {

    }
}
```

**EDIT**
Based on your comment:

> I want a class that can call the Load/Save methods but not be worried
>   that T is.

Then you'll need 2 interfaces: 1 for the load/save and then one with the parsing. In this case, you could use inheritance:

```
public interface IRecordedItems
{
    ObservableCollection<RecordedItem> Load( string name );
    void Save();
}


public interface IRecordedItemsProcessor<T> : IRecordedItems
{
    RecordedItem Parse( T itemToParse );
}

public class MyClass : IRecordedItems
{
    #region Implementation of IRecordedItems

    public ObservableCollection<RecordedItem> Load( string name )
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**EDIT 2**
Based on your [gist example](https://gist.github.com/3426916), the type dependency could be moved off of the interface and directly into the interface method:

```
public class RecordedItem {}

public interface IRecordedItemsProcessor
{
    ObservableCollection<RecordedItem> Load( string name );

    void Save();

    RecordedItem Parse<T>( T itemToParse );
}

public class MyClass
{
    private readonly IRecordedItemsProcessor _processor;

    public MyClass( IRecordedItemsProcessor processor )
    {
        _processor = processor;

        processor.Parse<string>( "foo" );
        processor.Parse<int>( 10 );
        processor.Parse<RecordedItem>( new RecordedItem() );
    }
}
```

Comment: How would IRecordedItemsProcessor<T> get injected into the method?

Comment: Before you consider using DI, consider how you'd want to use the generic in a concrete example. i.e., have you written up a working sample? If the usage is that `IRecordedItemsProcessor<T>` must be a constructor parameter, then `T` must be defined at the class level: `MyClass<T>`. DI wouldn't be injecting anything into the method since DI isn't used for executing methods. Rather, `IRecordedItemsProcessor<T>` could injected at the property level, but then again, the class would have to have `T` defined just as in the constructor example.

Comment: I understand that, its just generics I'm having the problem with. I want a class that can call the Load/Save methods but not be worried that T is. Whereever T is defined it seems it has to pass up the line to whatever touches it which in MyClass I dont want to do.

Comment: In that case, you could create an interface without the type parameter constraints and a 2nd interface inheriting from the first and including the type parameter constraint. See edit.

Comment: I've done something similar here however I dont like the concrete FileParser type dependency https://gist.github.com/3426916

Comment: We can move the type dependency off of the interface and directly into the method. I'll make another edit.

Comment: The only issue with that is in the actual method body of Parse you cannot do anything with T without a cast and alos makes it hard to unit test

Answer (score 0):

You could inherit from a non-generic marker interface, this removes the need to know about T in your class:

```
public interface IRecordedItemsProcessor 
{
}

public interface IRecordedItemsProcessor<T> : IRecordedItemsProcessor
{
    ObservableCollection<RecordedItem> Load(string name);
    void Save();
    RecordedItem Parse(T itemToParse);
}
```

And then you can use any IRecordedItemsProcessor like:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(IRecordedItemsProcessor processor)
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: this is nice solution, but what if you need access to generically typed processor in constructor?

Comment: @IlyaIvanov Since there was no code in the examples constructor I assumed the reference was just being saved. It could be cast later using a generic method avoiding the need to make the class itself generic. However, +1 for the approach in your answer, this is just another way of doing it.

Comment: Yes, you solution is good for quite a big amount of occasions. I bet you know, that simplicity is one of the keys in software development ;)